# How to set the value of a variable in the mocha router

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

I am creating some tests with mocha for my website and I am arriving to a problem:

I have a variable in the router that i am setting up when my server is answering to me by uploading a document on a page. My problem here is that I am not on this page when I run my tests and so, the variable is not defined.
I need to say that I am working with Backbone too.

In my router:

```
var router = new Router();
window.router = router;

window.router.streamId = "";
```

In my view:

```
initialize: function (options){
    this.idStream = options.streamId;
}
```

I was told to set it into the beforeEach but it appears that window.router is not defined at this time.

I also tried to do it in the "runner", the variable is defined when I arrive into the test page but it still displays the same error.

I hope I have been clear,

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to deal with this problem:

I set first the value of my var int the beforeEach:

```
var options = {streamId: "example_stream"};
```

I set the value of my var into the test:

```
it.only('should display the first search box', function(done) {
      $('#main').empty().append(new TraitementView(options).render().$el);
}
```